# getting sum of records based on date range in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

This is the table I created

```
CREATE TABLE "PaymentOut" (
    "poID"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "poSNO" INTEGER,
    "poMType"   TEXT,
    "poType"    TEXT,
    "poSubType" TEXT,
    "poName"    TEXT,
    "poDesc"    TEXT,
    "poAmount"  INTEGER,
    "poDate"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("poID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

[this is the data stored in PaymentOut table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36HnW.png)

what i want is to sum poAmount only if it is between specified date range

this query is what i am executing

```
SELECT p.poName,sum(CASE WHEN p.poAmount BETWEEN '12/1/2021' AND '12/30/2021' THEN p.poAmount ELSE 0 END) as Advance FROM PaymentOut p WHERE p.poSubType = 'emp' GROUP by   p.poName

OUTPUT OF Above query:
poName  Advance
Ikram   0
Rashid  0
Saeed   0


DesiredOutup ShouldBE:
poName  Advance
Ikram   100
Rashid  1000
Saeed   3000
```

I can get the output by running the query without specifying date

```
SELECT p.poName,sum(p.poAmount) as Advance FROM PaymentOut p WHERE p.poSubType = 'emp' GROUP by p.poName

poName  Advance
Ikram   100
Rashid  1000
Saeed   3000
```

but my requirement is to get this result with a given date range

Comment: i tried doing this but still in vain

SELECT p.poName,sum(CASE WHEN p.poAmount BETWEEN strftime('%d/%m/%Y','12/1/2021') AND strftime('%d/%m/%Y','12/30/2021') THEN p.poAmount ELSE 0 END ) as Advance FROM PaymentOut p WHERE p.poSubType = 'emp' GROUP by p.poName

Comment: when comparing with single date it works but not with date range which is desired in my situation


SELECT p.poName,sum(CASE WHEN p.poDate ='12/5/2021' THEN p.poAmount ELSE 0 END ) as Advance FROM PaymentOut p WHERE p.poSubType = 'emp' GROUP by p.poName

output:
Ikram 0
Rashid 1000
Saeed 2000

Comment: wow thank you it worked

Comment: sorry to bother you but it seems like formatting date  is not working anymore

Comment: Post sample data of your table as it is now after you changed the format.

Comment: @forpas 

`expense misc Beverages   80     2021-12-09
expenses emp Saeed  1000   2021-12-09
expenses emp Ikram   100    2021-12-09
expenses emp Rashid 1000    2021-12-20`

this is how date look in my table

and this is the query im running


`select p.poName,
sum(CASE WHEN p.poAmount BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-20' THEN p.poAmount ELSE 0 END) as adv 
FROM PaymentOut p WHERE p.poSubType = 'emp' GROUP by p.poName`

still getting 0

Comment: Don't compare poAmount to the dates. Change to `CASE WHEN poDate BETWEEN ....`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue thanks to @forpas and also by creating a view and putting   date range to where condition when querying that view.

What I was trying before: table data(note how dates are stored) looked something like this:

```
22  2   cash    expenses    emp Saeed       1000    12/5/2021
23  3   cash    expenses    emp Ikram       100     12/5/2021
24  4   cash    expenses    emp Rashid      1000    12/7/2021
25  5   cash    expenses    emp Saeed       1000    12/8/2021
26  6   cash    expenses    emp Rashid      1000    12/5/2021
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    p.poName, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.poAmount BETWEEN '12/1/2021' AND '12/30/2021' THEN p.poAmount ELSE 0 END) AS Advance 
FROM 
    PaymentOut p 
WHERE 
    p.poSubType = 'emp' 
GROUP BY
    p.poName
```

Output of this query:

```
poName  Advance
---------------
Ikram   0
Rashid  0
Saeed   0
```

First I changed the format of date to one @forpas mentioned this is how my data in table looks like:

```
22  2   cash    expenses    emp Saeed       1000    2021-12-09
23  3   cash    expenses    emp Ikram       100     2021-12-09
24  4   cash    expenses    emp Rashid      1000    2021-12-20
25  5   cash    expenses    emp Saeed       1000    2021-12-09
26  6   cash    expenses    emp Rashid      1000    2021-12-09
27  7   cash    expenses    emp Saeed       1000    2021-12-09
28  8   cash    expenses    emp Abdul       1000    2021-12-09
29  9   cash    expenses    emp Shahid      1000    2021-12-09
```

Then I created view and selected all the columns I require:

```
CREATE VIEW vempAdv 
AS 
    SELECT p.poName, p.poDate, p.poAmount 
    FROM PaymentOut p 
    WHERE p.poSubType = 'emp'
```

Then I ran a query against that view i.e

```
SELECT 
    poName,
    SUM(poAmount) AS adv 
FROM 
    vempAdv 
WHERE 
    poDate BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-20' 
GROUP BY
    poName
```

Output of that is:

```
Abdul   1000
Ikram   100
Rashid  2000
Saeed   3000
Shahid  1000
```

**Note**: data is changed from the question I asked.

@forpas thank you for taking your time and helping me out